# How to run a WPF project from a Windows Forms project?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I have two different projects, **project1** is a form project while **project2** is a WPF project. Is it possible if **button1** in **project1** is clicked, **project2** will run?

What I have tried doing so far is adding project2 as Reference and found out that .Show() method does not work here.

Answer (score 0):

You Probably need to add some more references to:

- PresentationFramework
- PresentationCore
- WindowsBase

Those assemblies are basic WPF assemblies and therefore they are necessary to open the window.